# Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie at javascript so sorry if my question is trivial, but I've trying to create a jquery plugin, but when I load the page I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
```

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

***html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"  http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
</head>
<body>
    //tags...
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    //tags...
</body>
</html>
```

***plugin:***

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myPlugin = function (...parameters...) {
            var ctx = this[0].getContext('2d');
            //
            body
            //
            return this;
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

***js:***

```
$(function () {
     //body
     $('#myCanvas').myPlugin(...parameters...);
     //body
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to add a value to a variable that hasn't been defined... But you haven't shown enough code for us to see where it's going wrong. Either debug your code line by line or post more for us to see.

Comment: What you posted looks pretty OK. Where are you using the variable named `canvas` exactly?

Comment: `(...parameters...)` I hope this isn't actually part of the JS...